# Generate text depends on another textbox value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to generate target textbox value depends on another textbox value with following conditions -

Assumed First **TextBox** value - "**myfile name**"

1. If first textbox value not start with "Copy of " then target value will "`Copy of [1] myfile name`".
2. If first textbox value "`Copy of [1] myfile name`" then target value will "`Copy of [2] myfile name`".
3. If first textbox value "`Copy of [2] myfile name`" then target value will "`Copy of [3] myfile name`".

i.e increment of the no.

**[Here is my code sample](https://jsfiddle.net/0xoa6Lb4/9/)**

How do I do this using jquery?

HTML:

```
<div class="panel">
  <input type="text" id="filename" value="filename">
</div>
<div class="panel">
  <input type="text" id="newfilename" value="">
</div>
<div class="panel">
  <button type="button" id="btnGenerate">
    Get File Name
  </button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#btnGenerate').click(function(){
  var newname;
    var oldname = $('#filename').val();
  if(typeof oldname !== undefined || oldname != ''){
    if(oldname.indexOf('Copy of')){
            var nCount = parseInt(oldname.match(/\([.*]\)/),10) + 1;
            newname = "Copy of [" + nCount[1] + "] " + oldname;
            $('#newfilename').val(newname); 
    }else{
        newname = "Copy of [1] " + oldname'
    }
    $('#newfilename').val(newname);

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0xoa6Lb4/29/)**.

You're so close, you've just to adjust the regex a little bitand add else statement :

```
$('#btnGenerate').click(function(){
  var oldname = $('#filename').val();
  if(typeof oldname !== undefined || oldname != ''){

    //Adding '>-1' in this condition
    if(oldname.indexOf('Copy of')>-1) 
    { 
      var nCount = parseInt(oldname.match(/\[(.*)\]/)[1],10) + 1;
      var file_name = oldname.split('] ')[1];

      var newname = "Copy of [" + nCount + "] " + file_name;
    }else{
      var newname = 'Copy of [1] '+oldname;
    }

    $('#newfilename').val(newname); 
  }
});
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('#btnGenerate').click(function(){
  var oldname = $('#filename').val();
  if(typeof oldname !== undefined || oldname != ''){
    if(oldname.indexOf('Copy of')>-1){
      var nCount = parseInt(oldname.match(/\[(.*)\]/)[1],10) + 1;
      var file_name = oldname.split('] ')[1];

      var newname = "Copy of [" + nCount + "] " + file_name;
    }else{
      var newname = 'Copy of [1] '+oldname;
    }

    $('#newfilename').val(newname); 
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel">
  <input type="text" id="filename" value="Copy of [1] filename">
</div>
<div class="panel">
  <input type="text" id="newfilename" value="">
</div>
<div class="panel">
  <button type="button" id="btnGenerate">
    Get File Name
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Is that what you looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

I've made the following adjustments to your code:

```
  if(oldname.substr(0, 7) == "Copy of"){
    var nCount = parseInt(oldname.match(/\[(\d+?)\]/)[1],10) + 1;
    var newname = oldname.replace(/\[\d+?\]/, "["+nCount+"]");
    $('#newfilename').val(newname);
  }
  else
  {
    $('#newfilename').val("Copy of [1] " + oldname); //prepend Copy of [1]
  }
```

Look at `oldname.substr(0, 7) == "Copy of"` the former `indexOf` skipped the if, not executing the code.

now `[(\d+?)\]` does the magic. It takes out all numbers between `[` and `]` and groups them in `()`. `\d+?` means get all numbers that occur 1 or n times. `?` makes it [lazy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions) so it stops at `]`.

`var newname = oldname.replace(/\[\d+?\]/, "["+nCount+"]")` simply do a replace on the `[]` block and replace it with `nCount`.

---

You can even optimize it using just a replace:

```
    var newname = oldname.replace(/\[(\d+?)\]/, function(whole, group1){
        return "[" + (parseInt(group1, 10)+1) + "]";
    });
```

```js
$('#btnGenerate').click(function(){
 var oldname = $('#filename').val();
    if(typeof oldname !== undefined || oldname != ''){
      if(oldname.substr(0, 7) == "Copy of"){
        var newname = oldname.replace(/\[(\d+?)\]/, function(whole, group1){
         return "[" + (parseInt(group1, 10)+1) + "]";
        });
        $('#newfilename').val(newname); 
      }
      else
      {
       $('#newfilename').val("Copy of [1] " + oldname); //prepend Copy of [1]
      }     
  }
});
```

```css
.panel{
  display:block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
.panel input{
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel">
  <input type="text" id="filename" value="Copy of [1] filename">
</div>
<div class="panel">
  <input type="text" id="newfilename" value="">
</div>
<div class="panel">
  <button type="button" id="btnGenerate">
    Get File Name
  </button>
</div>
```

---

On a whole different subject. You are building a filesystem kind of control. Wouldn't it be better that the copy amount is being determined by the amount of occurrences of that file name (and copies)?

Answer (score 0):

```js
names =  new Array()
$('#btnGenerate').click(function(){
 var oldname = $('#filename').val();
  names.push(oldname);
  if(oldname != ''){
    
var nCount  = $.grep(names, function (elem) {
    return elem === oldname;
}).length;
      var newname = "Copy of [" +nCount + "] " + oldname;
   $('#newfilename').val(newname);  
  }
 
});
```

```css
.panel{
  display:block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
.panel input{
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel">
  <input type="text" id="filename" value="Name">
</div>
<div class="panel">
  <input type="text" id="newfilename" value="">
</div>
<div class="panel">
  <button type="button" id="btnGenerate">
    Get File Name
  </button>
</div>
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: if the first name is "Copy of [1] Name" then target name will "Copy of [2] Name"

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working, but you have to change the regex from

```
 /\([.*]\)/ to /\d+/
```